# The import net.rim.device.api.util.StringProvider cannot be resolved

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

Using JRE 5.0.0:

`import net.rim.device.api.util.StringProvider;`

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/StringProvider.html

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure JRE 5 is actually enabled in your project?  Are you able to import other classes from `net.rim.device.api.util`?

Comment: see this link: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/package-summary.html.  In this link there is no "StringProvider" class in Version 5.0; It is from Version 6.0. I am not saying that your provided link is fake one; I am surprise one about your provided url; Better to put this question in http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/bd-p/java_dev link also;

Comment: Yeah, that link is wrong. I just thought trusting blackberry in this case made sense....guess I was wrong.

Comment: @alishaik786: you should post your comment as an Answer to get credit for it.  And yes, looking at the 6.0 and 7.0 docs show that `StringProvider` was added in 6.0, not 5.0.

Comment: Goodness gracious; I came across the same link trying into solve my down porting of my version 6.0 app. Does anyone know what going on here.

Comment: Error in the docs. StringProvides is 6.0 only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this link:

[Package net.rim.device.api.util](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/package-summary.html)

In this link there is **no** "StringProvider" class in **Version 5.0**; It is from **Version 6.0**. I am not saying that your provided link is fake one; I am surprise one about your provided url; Better to put this question in Blackberry supportforums:

[BlackBerry® Support Community Forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/bd-p/java_dev)

link also;

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've imported one of RIM's examples or created one of the default "Hello World" apps using the BlackBerry eclipse plugin. Unfortunately RIM's code has errors.

`StringProvider` does not exist in JRE5, try changing it to `StringBuffer`.